# Django InLineSetModel and many2many field choices filtering

Tags: django-admin

I have a many2many field in my model and I'm trying to render it in django admin using the inlineform. Everything is fine, but I can't customize the form as I want.

The model is simple there is a Supplier and a manytomany field named locations

```
Supplier(models.Model):
    location = models.ManyToManyfield(Location, blank=True)
```

the inlineform

```
class LocationInLineForm(admin.TabularInLine):
    model = Supplier.Location.through
```

The first thing I want to is to limit the choices. The constrains are two:

1. The location model has a boolean field 'active' and I need to filter based on that
2. The Supplier must be the Supplier selected in the django admin.

The admin user load the django admin, click on the supplier and the InLineForm must show his active location.

I thought that the following method is the right one to ovverride:

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
```

but is not called by the InLineForm. The on called is:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
```

The example in the django docs are based on the request.user but what I need is the current supplier where I can get it? In the request? But where? request.GET is empty. Maybe I can get it from db_field, but I don't know how.

If I can get the supplier id, I can create a queryset and pass it using **kwargs['queryset']**. Am I right?